# Validar coordenadas dentro de un polígono

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo un ms en springboot para validar si unas coordenadas(latitud, longitud) están dentro de un polígono previamente definido.

```
Punto 1: -38.68750711967124, -72.68457327069606
Punto 2: -38.68813914788199, -72.68296848437275
Punto 3: -38.688780103816896, -72.68343011690975
Punto 4: -38.688168934781345, -72.68492519454888

Posición dentro del polígono: -38.68811913797079, -72.68355687984929
Posición fuera del polígono : -38.68675112946928, -72.68677040517952
```

Los puntos forman una especie de cuadrado en un mapa y me gustaría determinar si las coordenadas están dentro, alguien conoce alguna librería o api que me permita determinarlo?
De no ser así, algún indicio de como poder resolver esta casuística?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java existe la clase `java.awt.geom.Path2D` con ella puedes ingresar todos los puntos para manejar un polígono y verificar si un punto se encuentra dentro de la figura, te muestro un ejemplo utilizando tus datos:

```
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class EjemploPoligono {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        //Definimos el primer punto como el punto de inicio con moveTo
        path.moveTo(-38.68750711967124, -72.68457327069606);
        // Utilizamos el método lineTo para ir definiendo las líneas
        path.lineTo(-38.68813914788199, -72.68296848437275);
        path.lineTo(-38.688780103816896, -72.68343011690975);
        path.lineTo(-38.688168934781345, -72.68492519454888);
        
        //Cerramos la figura geométrica en caso los puntos proporcionados no lo hagan.
        path.closePath();

        // Verificamos si las coordenadas están dentro con el método contains
        System.out.println(path.contains(-38.68811913797079, -72.68355687984929));
        System.out.println(path.contains(-38.68675112946928, -72.68677040517952));
    }
}


Salida:
true
false
```

Comment: Efectivamente la librería que mencionas fue útil para determinar si un punto está dentro del polígono, muchísimas gracias